# Hexadecimal to binary in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, binary, hex

I have this hexadecimal in a nodejs Tcp Client

```
82380000000000000400000000000000
```

I have used parseint function to convert it to

```
1.73090408076117e+38
```

But i need to get its binary representation that is

```
10000010001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Ho can i get this binary representation from the above hexadecimal format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the toString specifying the base as the parameter should make it. For example, if you want to convert it to a binary string, after parsing it to an integer:

```
var number = '82380000000000000400000000000000';
console.log(parseInt(number).toString(2));
```

In case you want an hexadecimal string, just use **.toString(16);**

If you don't want to parse the string with the number:

```
var number = 82380000000000000400000000000000;
console.log(number.toString(2));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not right. F is hexa while your answer says NaN. It actually does base 10 to base 2 untill you do the base to parseint like console.log(parseInt(number, 16).toString(2));